# Is specific OS build needed for specific ARM based device?

Tags: installation, operating-systems, arm

In a ARM based system is it necessary for the OS build to be specifically tailored for the system it is intended to be installed to?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike PCs built on x86 architecture, ARM devices do not have a standardized method of bootstrapping an operating system. Often on ARM devices, the bootstrapping is cryptographically locked to a specific operating system developed my a manufacturer and therefore must be unlocked in order to allow booting of other operating systems. Unlike PCs, these devices rarely allow booting from external storage devices, which means that an installation requires "flashing," or changing out the built in flash contents with a new operating system. This is also not standardized from one system to another.

In addition, ARM devices do not have standardized hardware interfaces like PCs, and therefore each operating system must be tailored to expect certain hardware features. PCs were designed with autodection of hardware in mind so that operating systems would be able to seamlessly run on a wide variety of hardware configurations. ARM devices were designed for specific applications and for mobile devices and therefore they do not have the same set of hardware standards that PCs have, necessitating a customization of an operating system for almost every ARM hardware set.

Answer (score 0):

An operating system needs to be built for the architecture in which it runs, as different processors have different command sets.

This is the reason why operating systems such as Windows will not run on a mobile device. You need to be sure that whichever OS you intend to use, will be ARM compatible.

Comment: For example, a windows or ubuntu standard setup disc plus driver setup would enable them to work on any x86 system. But in the case of ARM device, I find that, Android/Ubuntu standard setup ISO file is not available. They do have setup file but they are mentioned to be compatible only with certain boards or specific device. I was asking regarding in this aspect of it.